# Looping with different number of rows?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that works properly, however, the range is from I2:I800, which in some sheets there are less than 800 lines, so excel will fill the remaining ones with "0". Sometimes there are more than 800 line. What loop will help me just fill in as many rows there are?

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I2:I800")
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1] & TEXT(RC[-2],""00"")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("G:H").Delete

With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I2:I800")
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1] & TEXT(RC[-2],""00"")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("G:H").Delete
```

Comment: One comment on your history.  You have many questions, but only a few accepted answers.  Please go back through your history and accept those answers that are correct.  There are those that will stop helping without the feedback.  But more importantly it will remove the questions from the unanswered queue and reward those who answered correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No loop needed just find the last row.

```
Dim LstRow as Long
LstRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,8).End(xlup).Row
```

Then use that in your references

```
Dim LstRow as Long
LstRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,8).End(xlup).Row
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I2:I" & LstRow)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1] & TEXT(RC[-2],""00"")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("G:H").Delete

LstRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count,8).End(xlup).Row
With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I2:I" & LstRow)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1] & TEXT(RC[-2],""00"")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("G:H").Delete
```